# groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException while invoking web service from Spock groovy. Works fine from Postman or other clients

Tags: web-services, groovy, httpresponse, spock

I want to consume a webservice and add assertions to its response. I get the following exception:

```
groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException: 
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:495)
    ......
    at Subscription.Order Products(Subscription.groovy:14)
Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is 'I' with an int value of 73
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x52
```

My operation is as follows:

```
  def setupSpec() {
            client = new RESTClient("http://tsi-services-dev2.canaldigital.com:9080/test/webgw-dealer/v1/");
            client.handler.failure = { resp, data -> return resp }
        }
///// orderProductPayload is a variable which has an input
    def "Order Products"() {
            when:
            def resp = client.post(path: "order/orderProduct", requestContentType: JSON, contentType: JSON, body: orderProductPayload) as HttpResponseDecorator
            then:
            println("response: " + resp.data)
            resp.status == successResponseStatus
        }
```

I have other such tests too which work fine and this particular test with the input payload entered works fine from Postman

Here is my response headers for this operation which fails in spock/groovy:

```
Content-Length →159
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Wed, 05 Apr 2017 06:19:16 GMT
X-Correlation-ID → xxxxx
```

Response header for another opertion which is working:

```
  Connection →close
    Content-Length →273
    Content-Type →application/json
    Date →Wed, 05 Apr 2017 06:16:41 GMT
    X-Correlation-ID → xxxxx
```

Comment: This is the problem with response not wit the request, what response do you get? Probably this is not a valid JSON response.

Comment: @Opal i understand but i seem to get a correct response in postman or in soap ui.
If i remove the content type it gives a 400 response. with the content type i get this exception.
this is where im stuck because if the response were incorrect wouldnt it also have been an issue in postman etc. what do you think?

Comment: So check in and out headers in soapUI or postman and set the appropriately in groovy.

Comment: I edited my questions and pasted my response headers.
the 1st one is the one which doesnt work in spock whereas the 2nd one does. can you please take a look ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't debug it remotely with your hands :/ The only thing I can say is that response is spoilt somehow.

Comment: I understand. thanks anyways :)
if you have any suggestion on an alternate or better way of doing things do let me know please. 
Thanks again

Comment: Well, you could just post the JSON here by editing your question.

Comment: You can use [wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#rest), which is very light weight in your case and see if that helps

Comment: Hi all. Thanks alot for the help
turns out there was a special character such as Ø in my request which the service didnt like and hence was responding in such an absurd way. Works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot for the help turns out there was a special character such as Ø in my request which the service didnt like and hence was responding in such an absurd way. Works fine now